# Abstract classes Scala. Bug in a tutorial and anonymous classes

Tags: scala

I'm reading this blog post [here](https://commitlogs.com/2016/10/01/scala-trait-and-abstract-class/)

I'm following along and my Scala Worksheet in yelling at me that the method isn't defined correctly:

This works:

```
abstract class Pet {
    var age: Int = 0
    val hello: String
    val greeting: String = s"I like to play with you!"
    def sayHello: Unit = { println(hello) }
    override def toString = s"$hello, $greeting"
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
abstract class Pet {
    var age: Int = 0
    val hello: String
    val greeting: String = s"I like to play with you!"
    def sayHello: = { println(hello) }
    override def toString = s"$hello, $greeting"
}
```

The error just says `wrong type`

Why does this not work? What is going on? Is the blog post wrong?

```
println(new Pet {
    val hello = "Meow2"
})
```

It returns this:

```
Meow2, I like to play with you!
res5: Unit = ()
```

Can you just instantiate abstract classes? I'm reading the Odersky book right now and where does he go into this syntax? It doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax error is here:

```
def sayHello: = { println(hello) }
```

The `:` must have a type after it. You can do this:

```
def sayHello: Unit = { println(hello) }
```

Or you can do this:

```
def sayHello = { println(hello) }
```

In the latter option, the type is inferred.

As for abstract classes, no, you cannot instantiate them. Technically what is going on in that example is declaring an anonymous subclass of that abstract class, and instantiating that. These two are pretty much the same:

```
println(new Pet {
    val hello = "Meow2"
})


class Cat2 extends Pet {
    val hello = "Meow2"
}
println(new Cat2)
```

Comment: But where is that being done? Is that being done by the compiler and what I'm writing is just shorthand? Is that code equivalent being written in Java bytecode by the compiler or is there an intermediate step before the compiler that autogenerates that code?

Comment: Why is Cat2 anonymous? It has a name no?

Comment: In the first version (from the blog post) you're defining and instantiating a class all in one statement. That class doesn't have a name (it's anonymous) so you can't refer to it again elsewhere. That's in contrast to the example I posted with Cat2, which is *not* anonymous. In both cases the compiler will generate pretty much the same byte code. The anonymous class will have some arbitrary generated name. Works identically in Java.